# C# Starting Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio

is there a way that I can have a template (Of my own choice) when I open up Visual studio. I know in C++ I go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcprojectitem\newc++file` and I can open the `newc++file` file and paste my template there. I'm in college and our teachers wants us to have a few lines at the start as a description of what the program is our names etc, and I don't want to have to copy paste/type it in every time.

Comment: I don't know about visual studio, but using MonoDevelop, one of the properties of a project is to modify the header. The advantage is that this is done on project level, and projects you write for work/fun are not modified by this...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create a project template.

1. Create a project.
2. Add/delete/modify files.
3. Go to *File* → *Export Template* → *Export Template*, click *Project
   Template* and then follow the wizard.

[See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.90).aspx).

And then, when you create a new project you can select this template.

You can do it several way, but in my point of view, this one is the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Export Template wizard as answered by @Valentin or you can manually modify the existing templates.

Templates for C# will be found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.x\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp..."

Find your required template and modify the cs files there. It will be used when you create new project using that template.

[How to: Update Existing Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx)

Comment: In  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.x\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp..." There are 147 folders... What am I suppost to replace with my template? It's for Windows Form Applications

Comment: @RichardRoy I hope you're looking for  folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.x\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\WindowsApplication

Comment: So I just copy everything from my exported template into this location?

Comment: I got it, Thanks everyone!

Comment: @RichardRoy Yes you can do that. Or just modify the files in there which would also work. To be in safer side, take a backup of that folder in case if something goes wrong.